# SQL: How to assign the same line number to lines with the same value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below in SQL Server. I reach the row number values with using `ROW_NUMBER` partition function. But this was not the result I wanted to achieve.

| RowNumber | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | D |

I want to get this table

| RowNumber | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

How can I do it, do you have a function suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VALUE), VALUE
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Value) RowNumber, Value
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Value;
```